# How to Implement QR code on Brightscript (roku) channel?

Tags: qr-code, roku, brightscript

I want to implement QR on my Roku channel. I have implemented random code to display on the TV screen. Random codes get authenticated me for the login process.

I want dynamic Qr generator to be implemented on that random code section. So that user can scan the QR code from mobile devices or mobile application to get authentication code and login successfully.
So, What are the approaches that make me implement dynamic Qr code on my Roku applications?
I have made a search for any external libraries but I cannot get exact results.
I also have found a document regarding brightsign. But, there are some codes regarding Html and javascript implementation. I have confused with this all.
So, If there is anyone who can help me with detail about this implementation process.
Thank you in advance.

To get QR code displayed on the Roku channel and code must be generated dynamically on the client side.
Have to be scannable by mobile devices and provide me for authentication.

Comment: Why do you want to encode the random data in qr code? Your qrcode should be a static one pointing to the url where your service hosts. Once user navigates to your service then your service should ask user to enter the code display in the roku tv screen and then authentication process kicks in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution (unless you find an already written QR-generator Brightscript implementation) would be to host an existing open source QR generating software on a server and have your Roku application contact the server to send the data and receive an image URL in response.

I haven't tried so can't vouch for it but this could be an option https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/

Comment: Thank You for your response I have implemented the same logic there now it's done

Comment: Subash is that brs source something that you can share?